# rEFInd is no longer booting windows

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, refind

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu, and windows 10 in a dual boot setup. Unfortunately, windows was misbehaving and kept setting itself as a priority boot, so I chose to install rEFInd on ubuntu. When doing so, somehow the installation went wrong and the refind.conf file is in /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/Microsoft and when I configure the refind.conf file to have a windows menu entry to bootmgr.efi it just reopens refind. This leads me to believe that my windows boot manager has somehow been swapped with refind. I could be wrong, but in either case can someone please help, I cant boot my windows and I'd rather not completely reinstall everything. (I would also not mind if there is a way to restore everything to a previous time)

Comment: On some PC's (e.g. some HP's), the only way I've found to get Ubuntu and Windows to coexist is to manually backup and then rename the MS boot efi file, replacing it with a renamed grubx64.efi. See https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/bootrepair.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think if I am able to boot windows I will definitely back up and do so in the future.